# Matlab including wrong file into mcc

Tags: matlab, mcc

### Scenario:

- I'm compiling a project which uses a lot of external files\functions.
- When I compile, I use a function which includes all of said files into the mcc command with the '-a' argument.
- Everything seems to be in place and working fine after compilation, **EXCEPT** one text file - in which case, Matlab seem to include a text file (with the same name) from an earlier iteration of the project (I can tell, because the text in the file is different).

### Some more details:

- When I include the external files, I do so by adding the paths of all the sub-folders residing in the directory of the project.
- After compilation is done, all of said paths are removed from Matlab's paths.
- No paths other than Matlab's default paths are added before and after compilation.
- **When I run the project from the .m file, the correct text file is used, but after compilation, the wrong one is used.**

### Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the -a includes everything in a directory, even those not on the MATLAB path. I have also had problems of files having the same name, perhpas only differing by case with compiled programs. So do not have two files, or rename one of them.

What I would prefer, if I were doing this, is not use the -a flag. Everything you need for your project should be in one directory, so there are no confusions in the compilation with other files in other directories.